# Windows batch: How can I ran multiple aliases in single line

Tags: windows, batch-file, alias

I'd like to set alias for combination of aliases.

My aliases are declared like this:

```
doskey h=cd c:\sources\dev\folder1
doskey t=cd c:\sources\dev\folder2
```

I'd like to create alias that performs sequence of operations. Like this:

```
h && somecommand && t
```

But, when I run this, only first command gets executed. Where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can execute multiple aliases in one line.

I assume it is because of [this little nugget](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx):

> You cannot run a doskey macro from a batch program

You can however put multiple commands in a single alias:

```
doskey test=dir $T echo dir completed...
```

Answer (score 0):

Anders already anwsered the question, something I want to fillup is that the **syntax** should be "^&" rather than "&", so the command should like

```
doskey test = cd c:\sources\dev\folder1 ^&^& somecommand ^&^& cd c:\sources\dev\folder2
```